# jQuery only numbers and px/em input

Tags: jquery, numbers, autofill

I am trying that people can fill in pixels or ems in a inputfield but i want it a little nicer with a check / autofill.

Ths is the jQuery script what i now have:

```
$options.keydown(function (e) {
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter, dot, e, m , p, x
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190, 69, 77, 80, 88]) !== -1 ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
        (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) || 
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
             return;
    }
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

So people can only put in the numbers, the dot or type in px or em. But how can i autofill the input when a person only types in "20"? It would be nice that the input will autofill it to "20px". And when the person is just typing in "eeee" in the field that it will be cleared. So only the format "px" or "em" are allowed. And when somewone don't type in a unit then the input will auto fill it with "px" behind it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the script that is working for me now:

```
jQuery('.units input').on('change', function() {

    e = jQuery(this).val();
    units(e);
    jQuery(this).val(e);

});

var units = function( value) {
    if ( jQuery.isNumeric(value) ) {
        e = value + 'px';
        return e;
    } else if ( value.indexOf('px') > -1  || value.indexOf('em') > -1  ) {
        var Pixels  = e.replace("px", "");
        var Ems  = e.replace("em", "");
        if ( jQuery.isNumeric(Pixels) || jQuery.isNumeric(Ems) ) {
            e = value;
            return e;
        } else {
            e = "0px";
            return e;
        }
    } else {
        e = "0px";
        return e;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not simply just use type="number" on the input field? And append the unit value inside JS, or alternatively a second form field (select, with options).

Comment: type=number is HTML5 so with older browsers i can have a problem then. And i dont want to make the overview messy so i want to scale down the form fields and if this is possble then i can clean the form alot!